# How to return distinct multi-word strings from blocks of usage log text with POSIX?

Tags: sql, regex, substring, posix, amazon-redshift

First time poster and still learning the ropes, so I apologize if the description below is overly verbose.

I have a database of usage logs I'm pulling data from via various pre-parsed fields. This query is intended to return the count of how many times a distinct error signature was logged over a given period of time. Each logged error is assigned a `signature_id`, errors of the same type are all assigned the same `signature_id`. One of the fields I'm returning in my query, `message`, returns the entire message stack trace/block of usage log text.

I want my query to group by `signature_id`, which is a pre-parsed field in the table I'm selecting from. I'm struggling to make it work because, while similar error types are assigned the same `signature_id', every usage log differs slightly due to the timestamp of when the message was logged. So my query is grouping by`message`instead of`signature`.

EX: Of what my query returns if I return the entire usage log `message`

```
signature_id    
b2dea422 

message
2019-01-17 18:01:52,130 ip-BLANK [WARN ][159] [request_id=00e74d7c] Type=Blank.Multiverse.Web.Mvc.Attributes.Usage+UsageLoggingException Message=UsageLogContext not present in HttpContext.Current.Items Data: Signature=b2dea422 Stack Trace: at Blank.Blank.Web.Mvc.Attributes.Usage.GetUsageLogContext() at Blank.Blank.Web.Mvc.Attributes.Usage.AddData(Object data)

count
1

signature_id    
b2dea422 

message
2019-01-17 16:21:36,681,130 ip-BLANK [WARN ][38] [request_id=c140f8ea] Type=Blank.Multiverse.Web.Mvc.Attributes.Usage+UsageLoggingException Message=UsageLogContext not present in HttpContext.Current.Items Data: Signature=b2dea422 Stack Trace: at Blank.Blank.Web.Mvc.Attributes.Usage.GetUsageLogContext() at Blank.Blank.Web.Mvc.Attributes.Usage.AddData(Object data)

count
1
```

I mentioned above that every usage log differs due to the timestamp of when a given message was logged, but similar error types are assigned the same `signature_id`. Similar error types *also* share the same `Exception Message=`...

EX: Every time a message is logged with `signature_id=ab7d890pq`, it will also have `Exception Message=Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` in the message block.

Since the table I'm selecting from doesn't have a pre-parsed `exception_message` field, I want to parse out the `Exception Message=` string so my GROUP BY will return the count of distinct logged `signature_id`'s and a column with the exception message is for each distinct signature.

My current query shown below begins to parse out the exceptionmessgage string, but I can't get it to return the entire string:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN sourcecategory = 'source_hello_world_category' THEN 'hwCategory'
       END AS Service,
       signature,
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, 'Message=\\w+[[:space:]]+'), 9), '') AS exceptionmessage,
       count(*)
FROM user_usage_logs
WHERE (signature IS NOT NULL
       AND signature NOT IN ('ccce9e73',
                             '787dd1b5',
                             '17fc66bc',
                             'ca384d1f',
                             '20121ecb',
                             'ccce9e73'))
  AND sourcecategory IN ('source_hello_world_category')
  AND messagetime > (getdate() - 1)
GROUP BY signature,
         sourcecategory,
         exceptionmessage
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The code shown above returns:

```
signature_id   exceptionmessage        count

b1det422       Cannot                  31,321
330ope77       Unauthorized            1,207
53m6m466       Reference               311
```

This is an example of I *want* returned:

```
signature_id   exceptionmessage                                  count

b1det422       Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Stack     31,321
330ope77       Unauthorized access response for many users       1,207
53m6m466       Reference cannot be set to an empty.object.3      311
```